# angularjs adding a form to a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Take the following code example:

```
app.config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider){
     $stateProvider
        .state('route1', {

            url: "/ID/:slug",
            templateUrl: "/static/html/main-view.html",
            controller: "CampaignCtrl"
        })

etc...
```

The template `main-view.html` just shows a list of items. I now want to add simple sign-up form to the page, but what is the correct approach *(an example would be good too)*.

```
1) just stick it in the main-view.html, downside is I cannot use it on its own
2) somehow attach another controller no idea how.
3) create a custom directive that accepts prarms to create a form if thats possible.
4) something else?
```

Comment: if want form displayed with list and use it eleswehere can use `ng-include` for list display, and can use same templateUrl for a `state` if you want a standalone version. Or use it in another place for `edit`. Similarly could wrap form in a directive. Angular is extremely flexible. As for wanting examples... would help if you create demo first

Comment: You can add in an extra controller wherever you need to with ng-controller, you don't need to depend on the router to supply the controllers for views.  In any HTML element simply add ng-controller="MyLoginCtrl" to add a controller.